# SQL: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I'm pretty new to SQL and currently working with MS SQL Server Management Studio. I've been given an assignment where I have to make a database with certain tables in it. Two of those tables are named "Products" and "Categories". After creating all the tables I had to populate them(insert records in them) and it's here where I got stuck.

This is the code for creating the two tables:

Categories table:

```
CREATE TABLE Categories (
    CategoryID NCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
```

Products table:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProductID INT identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Single Price] MONEY NOT NULL,
    CategoryID NCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES Categories(CategoryID));
```

Here I'm inserting data into the Categories table:

```
INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryID, Name)
VALUES ('BKS', 'Books'),
       ('MSC','Music'),
       ('HDW', 'Hardware'),
       ('SFW', 'Software');
```

So far so good. And here is where the problem arises!
I'm trying to insert data into the Products table like this:

```
INSERT INTO Products (Name, [Single Price], CategoryID)
VALUES ('SQL for Dummies', 39.99, 'BKS'),
       ('The Power of Now', 24.99, 'BKS'),
       ('Steve Jobs: The Book', 29.99, 'BKS'),
       ('Eminem albums', 19.99, 'MSC'),
       ('Jay Z albums', 23.99, 'MSC'),
       ('Notorious B.I.G. albums', 24.99, 'MSC'),
       ('GeForce GT 710 2GB graphics card', 49.99, 'HDW'),
       ('2 TB T3 SSD', 79.99, 'HDW'),
       ('Acer Curved Gaming monitor', 259.99, 'HDW'),
       ('MS SQL Server Management Studio', 59.99, 'STW'),
       ('Visual Studio 2015', 69.99, 'SFW'),
       ('GTA V', 79.99, 'SFW');
```

And I get the following error:

"**The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Products__Catego__99BF96C4". The conflict occurred in database "HackCompany", table "dbo.Categories", column 'CategoryID'.**

The statement has been terminated."

If anyone has an any help to offer, everything will be appreciated!

Comment: One or more of the categories is not in the categories table.  For your sample data, that would be `'STW'`.

Comment: Oh, damn! Thanks a bunch, I can't believe I didn't see this one! Definitely fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that one or more categories are not in the data.  You can find this with a `select` statement:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (VALUES ('SQL for Dummies', 39.99, 'BKS'),
             ('The Power of Now', 24.99, 'BKS'),
             ('Steve Jobs: The Book', 29.99, 'BKS'),
             ('Eminem albums', 19.99, 'MSC'),
             ('Jay Z albums', 23.99, 'MSC'),
             ('Notorious B.I.G. albums', 24.99, 'MSC'),
             ('GeForce GT 710 2GB graphics card', 49.99, 'HDW'),
             ('2 TB T3 SSD', 79.99, 'HDW'),
             ('Acer Curved Gaming monitor', 259.99, 'HDW'),
             ('MS SQL Server Management Studio', 59.99, 'STW'),
             ('Visual Studio 2015', 69.99, 'SFW'),
             ('GTA V', 79.99, 'SFW')
      ) as v(Name, [Single Price], CategoryID)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from categories c where v.categoryID = c.categoryID)
```

Comment: Wow, that's a very neat way to find the problematic entry. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The category 'STW' not exist in table